# How to make a jQuery promise from another promise

Tags: jquery, promise, resolve

I am writing a basic repository based on $.getJSON() and HTML5's sessionStorage as a cache.

When data is requested the first time, repository reads the data from a web service and stores it in sessionStorage, so the next time data is read from cache. The following is the code of my repository for working with Task entity:

```
Storage.prototype.setObject = function (key, value) { this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value)); };
Storage.prototype.getObject = function (key) { return JSON.parse(this.getItem(key)); };

var repository = function () {
    var getTasks = function () {
        if (sessionStorage.getObject("Tasks") {
            return $.Deferred().resolve(sessionStorage.getObject("Tasks")).promise();
        }
        else {
            return $.getJSON("/gettasks").done(function (data) {
                sessionStorage.setObject("Tasks", data);
            }).promise();
        }
    }

    var findTask = function (id) {
        var item;
        return getTasks().done(function (tasks) {
            for(var t in tasks)
                if(tasks[t].id == id)
                    item = tasks[t];
        }).resolve(item);
    }

    return {
        getTasks: function () { return getTasks(); },
        findTask: function (id) { return findTask(id); }
    };
}();
```

The return type of **getTasks** is a jQuery promise in anyway (whether data is read from web service or from cache). Here is the usage of repository in my client code:

```
repository.getTasks().done(function (tasks) {
    // display list
}).fail(function(err) {
    // show error
});
```

Now what I want is another function for finding a task by its id through the same way. So I need **findTask** function to call **getTasks** function and then try to find the task item in the list by id. My problem is now to return a single task item in the promise. But the find method is now returning the whole list (basically it's returning the result of getTasks function). But I need it the same way I read the list like below:

```
repository.findTask(765).done(function (task) {
    // display task item 765
}).fail(function(err) {
    // show error
});
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [deferred.then](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/)

```
var findTask = function (id) {
    return getTasks().then(function (tasks) {
        for (var t in tasks) {
            if (tasks[t].id == id) {
                return tasks[t];
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2xvAW/)

Note: One problem with this approach is even if the item is not found the done callback will get called.

Another solution is to create your own deferred like

```
var findTask = function (id) {
    var deferred= jQuery.Deferred();
    getTasks().done(function (tasks, status, xhr) {
        for (var t in tasks) {
            if (tasks[t].id == id) {
                deferred.resolveWith(this, [tasks[t]]);
                return;
            }
            deferred.reject(xhr, 'error', 'NOT FOUND');
        }
    }).fail(function(xhr, status, textStatus){
        deferred.reject.apply(deferred, arguments);
    });

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/S7mpN/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes *then* worked. I will find out a way for done callback. Thanks again and sorry i dont have enough reputation to vote up :(